# Importing sklearn in Databricks downgrades the Python root logger?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, azure-databricks, python-logging

Using Python 3.8.10 in an Azure Databricks notebook, runtime 10.4:

```py
>>> import logging
>>> type(logging.root)
logging.RootLogger
```

Ok, that was expected. What's surprising is this:

```py
>>> import sklearn  # version is 1.1.3
>>> import logging
>>> type(logging.root)
numpy.distutils.log.Log
```

This is problematic because numpy's `Log` is not as powerful as Python's; in particular, it can't print exception tracebacks (and crashes when attempting to). (NumPy version is 1.23.5.)

I failed to reproduce the problem in a local Python installation, with exactly the same versions of Python, scikit-learn, and numpy.

In order to debug this, I opened `site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py` with vim in the Databricks Web Terminal, and injected some `raise RuntimeError`s in various places, in an attempt to find out *where* in that file the root logger was getting replaced. Again I encountered surprising behavior: if I add a `raise RuntimeError("blah")` as the *last line* of `__init__.py`, then the interpreter *does* parse that file and hit the raise line, but the root logger does *not* get replaced:

```py
>>> try:
...     import sklearn
... except Exception as e:
...     print(repr(e))
RuntimeError('blah')
>>> import logging
>>> type(logging.root)
logging.RootLogger
```

I would like to understand how to debug this. In Python, when I write `import sklearn`, what happens *after* the interpreter runs the last line of `sklearn/__init__.py`, and before the interpreter runs the first line after `import sklearn`?

Comment: Not sure if you are still facing this issue but I ran into a similar bug in my setup. I was able to resolve the issue by updating numpy to the latest version.